# How to add an "active" class to navbar in sveltekit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to set `path` when a route changes, but its not updating:

```
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    let path;

    function getPath() {
        path = $page.url.pathname;
        console.log(path);
    }

    $: $page.url.pathname;
    $: getPath();
</script>

<aside>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class={path === '/' ? 'active' : ''}>
                <a href="/"><img src="/icons/compass.svg" alt="" border="0" />Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class={path === '/messages' ? 'active' : ''}>
                <a href="/messages"><img src="/icons/messages.svg" alt="" border="0" /> Messages</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>

<style>
    nav li.active a {
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

THis isn't updating when i change routes in browser.

Comment: If you're reading this thread you may also want to see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613169/sveltekit-styling-active-links-with-page-path

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because Svelte doesn't know to re-run the `getPath()` function. To fix this, you can pass the pathname as an argument so that Svelte knows to re-run the function when the path changes.

```svelte
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    let path;

    function getPath(currentPath) {
        path = currentPath;
        console.log(path);
    }

    $: getPath($page.url.pathname);
</script>
```

You could also simplify this to not use a function at all, if you're only updating the `path` variable.

```svelte
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    let path;

    $: path = $page.url.pathname;
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let dashboardActive = false;
if(window.location.pathname == '/dashboard'){
    dashboardActive = true;
}

<a class="mainmenuNew" href="/dashboard" >
    {#if dashboardActive}
        <span class="mainmenuImg"><img class='icnImg' src="/leftmenu/dashboard-active.png"></span>
        <span class="mainmenutext activemenutxt" >Dashboard</span>
    {:else}
        <span class="mainmenuImg"><img class='icnImg' src="/leftmenu/dashboard.png"></span>
        <span class="mainmenutext" >Dashboard</span>
    {/if}
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</a>
```